# Quarkus OpenApi custom filename

Tags: java, maven, openapi, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus with Java 11 and I'm trying to configure the OpenApi specification with Swagger with static files (see [link](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#loading-openapi-schema-from-static-files)). In the docs of Quarkus it is recommended to use `META-INF/openapi.yml` but I prefer not the name `openapi` for the `.yml` file but the name of my microservice. It is possible only if I configure [an additional docs directory](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#quarkus-smallrye-openapi_quarkus.smallrye-openapi.additional-docs-directory) with the directory e.g. `META-INF`. It will scan the desired folder for `.yaml`/`.yaml` and/or `.json` files. But this feels like a workaround to me. Is it possible to configure that Quarkus is scanning for a custom filename instead of a folder?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a workaround.  The standard name of the file is openapi.yml, if you do not want to have it then you need to provide a custom one, under a specific directory.  That is how smallrye does it, and Quarkus uses SmallRye

Example:

https://github.com/watermelonjam/openapi-docs-bug

[image]

application.yml

```
quarkus:
  log:
    level: INFO
    min-level: TRACE
    console:
      enable: true
      format: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%t] %-5p %c %M - %s%e%n"
    category:
      io.extr.odb:
        level: INFO
  swagger-ui:
    always-include: false
  smallrye-openapi:
    auto-add-security: false
    additional-docs-directory: META-INF/openapi/prod
```

Folder structure:

```
resources/META-INF/openapi/prod/someFile.yaml
```